# Aggregate multiple select statements without replicating data

Tags: sql, postgresql

How do I aggregate 2 select clauses without replicating data.

For instance, suppose I have `tab_a` that contains the data from 1 to 10:

```
|id|
|1 |
|2 |
|3 |
|. |
|. |
|10|
```

And then, I want to generate the combination of `tab_b` and `tab_c` making sure that result has 10 lines and add the column of `tab_a` to the result tuple

Script:

```
SELECT tab_b.id, tab_c.id, tab_a.id
from tab_b, tab_c, tab_a;
```

However this is replicating data from `tab_a` for each combination of `tab_b` and `tab_c`, I only want to add and would that for each combination of tab_b x tab_c I add a row of tab_a.

Example of data from tab_b

```
|id|
|1 |
|2 |
```

Example of data from tab_c

```
|id|
|1 |
|2 |
|3 |
|4 |
|5 |
```

I would like to get this output:

```
|tab_b.id|tab_c.id|tab_a.id|
|1       |1       |1       |
|2       |1       |2       |
|1       |2       |3       |
|...     |...     |...     |
|2       |5       |10      |
```

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. Could you please share some sample data from `tab_b` and `tab_c` and the result you'd like to get for that sample?

Comment: Looks like you want to add a `ROW_NUMBER`?

Comment: @dnoeth in this particular example yes, but not always. my tab_a could have not serial id data, and I am not using id in my real scenario.

Comment: Then it's a ROW_NUMBER in a CROSS JOIN between table b and c and a ROW_NUMBER on table a  and a join on those ROW_NUMBERs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you're new to SQL, but this is generally not the way things are done with RDBMSs. Anyway, if this is what you need, PostgreSQL can deal with it nicely, using different strategies:

#### Window Functions:

```
with
  tab_a (id) as (select generate_series(1,10)),
  tab_b (id) as (select generate_series(1,2)),
  tab_c (id) as (select generate_series(1,5))

select tab_b_id, tab_c_id, tab_a.id
from (select *, row_number() over () from tab_a) as tab_a
left join (
  select tab_b.id as tab_b_id, tab_c.id as tab_c_id, row_number() over ()
  from tab_b, tab_c
  order by 2, 1
  ) tabs_b_c ON (tabs_b_c.row_number = tab_a.row_number)
order by tab_a.id;
```

#### Arrays:

```
with
  tab_a (id) as (select generate_series(1,10)),
  tab_b (id) as (select generate_series(1,2)),
  tab_c (id) as (select generate_series(1,5))

select bc[s][1], bc[s][2], a[s]
from (
  select array(
           select id
           from tab_a
           order by 1
           ) a,
         array(
           select array[tab_b.id, tab_c.id]
           from tab_b, tab_c
           order by tab_c.id, tab_b.id
           ) bc
     ) arr
join lateral generate_subscripts(arr.a, 1) s on true
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question includes an unstated, invalid assumption: that the *position* of the values in the table (the row number) is meaningful in SQL.  It's not.  In SQL, rows have *no order*.  All joins -- everything, in fact -- are based on values.  To join tables, you have to supply the values the DBMS should use to determine which rows go together.

You got a hint of that with your attempted join: `from tab_b, tab_c, tab_a`.  You didn't supply any basis for joining the rows, which in SQL means there's no restriction: all rows are "the same" for the purpose of this join.  They all match, and *voila*, you get them all!

To do what you want, redesign your tables with at least one more column: the key that serves to identify the value.  It could be a number; for example, your source data might be an array.  More commonly each value has a name of some kind.

Once you have tables with keys, I think you'll find the join easier to write and understand.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question correctly maybe this is what you are looking for ..

```
SELECT bctable.b_id, bctable.c_id, atable.a_id
  FROM (SELECT a_id, ROW_NUMBER () OVER () AS arnum FROM a) atable
       JOIN (SELECT p.b_id, p.c_id, ROW_NUMBER () OVER () AS bcrnum
               FROM (  SELECT b.b_id, c.c_id
                         FROM b CROSS JOIN c
                     ORDER BY c.c_id, b.b_id) p) bctable
          ON atable.arnum = bctable.bcrnum
```

Please check the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d95e4/11) .